# Diferencia entre finish() y onBackPressed()

Tags: android

Bueno pues como indica el título, ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre el método `finish()` y `onBackPressed()`?

Comment: has leido la documentación? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()

Comment: Te dejo mi respuesta con casos prácticos, verás las diferencias y usos

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`finish()` destruye una actividad y no podrás acceder a ella hasta que la vuelvas a crear.

`onBackPressed()` vuelve a la Actividad o Fragmento anterior al que te encuentras en el momento, todo depende de como lo hayas programado.

Por ejemplo si al cambiar de actividad destruyes la anterior con `finish()`, al hacer `onBackPressed()` no va a encontrar la anterior y te va a cerrar la aplicación lo que te puede dar la sensación de que es un `finish()` pero no lo es, solo te ha puesto la app en segundo plano (creo que por esto puedes tener la confusión).

**Actividad A -> Actividad B `finish()`-> Actividad C**

En este caso si te encuentras en la **Actividad C** y haces un `onBackPressed()` va a volver a la Activiad A.

**Actividad B `finish()` -> Actividad C**

En este caso si te encuentras en la **Actividad C** y haces un `onBackPressed()` deja la app en segundo plano

Comment: Hola! solo un alcance.. se supone que si sobreescribimos la funcion de retroceso, es porque nosotros sabemos bien que hacer y porque. Me explico y te cito "l hacer onBackPressed() no va encontrar la anterior y te va a cerrar la aplicación lo que te puede dar la sensación de que es un  finish()"... eso correcto, pero si el usuario sobreescribe el `onBackPressed()` es el quien debe indicar a que Activity volver! si no, no tendria logica sobreescribir este metodo. Saludos!

Comment: "al cambiar de actividad cierras la anterior con finish(), al hacer onBackPressed() no va encontrar la anterior" si se cierra no se va a  poder ejecutar onBackPressed() porque ya no existe. Dar la sensación de  finish() no creo ya que es diferente, una cierra y la otra puede llamar finish() para destruir la Activity. =(

Answer (score 3):

### finish()

Es una función para finalizar la actividad, sacándola de la pila de actividades.

Navegación entre actividades de forma natural

`A->B->C` al pulsar atrás `C->B->A`

Si se usa `finish()` en alguna actividad

`A->B(finish)->C` pulsar atrás `C->A`

Un caso práctico seria una splashcreen, que cuando termine su carga pase a otra actividad, pero eliminando de la pila, así si el usuario realiza la acción volver atrás, saldrá de la app.

SplasCreenActivity.java

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
finish();
```

### OnBackPressed()

Es para detectar el evento retroceder, cuando el usuario realiza la acción de volver atrás, usando el botón físico, el virtual o el `UpNavButton`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
...
}
```

Lo usos pueden ser variados, prevenir la salida de la app mientras hay alguna tarea en funcionamiento, computar la doble pulsación para salir de la app...

Answer (score 2):

El botón de retroceso llama por defecto a `finish()` pero si tu quieres sobreescribir este metodo, agregar código antes de que vuelva a atrás y termine una `Activity` debes crear el metodo `onBackPressed()`.

También existe la manera de identificar cuando se presiona el botón de retroceso

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
        //codigo adicional
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Pero lo correcto sería :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //codigo adicional
        this.finish();
}
```

**EDICIÓN**

Al sobre escribir el método `onBackPressed()` el usuario debiese saber porque lo sobre escribe, si quiere volver a la `Activity` anterior sin no hacer ningún cambio no tiene sentido. Sin embargo, pondré une ejemplo. Si queremos modificar el evento de retroceso y advertirle al usuario "Está seguro de salir" es indicado sobre escribir este método **Y** decirle al método que tiene que volver a la `Activity` anterior o a la que el usuario quiera.

Cito a @FabioVenturiPastor

> Por ejemplo si al cambiar de actividad cierras la anterior con finish(), al hacer onBackPressed() no va encontrar la anterior y te va a cerrar la aplicación lo que te puede dar la sensación de que es un  finish() pero no lo es, solo te ha puesto la app en segundo plano (creo que por esto puedes tener la confusión).

Como explique arriba, si el usuario sobre escribe el método y no hace ningún tipo de adicional código y tampoco especifica que `activity` debe volver no tiene sentido alguno.

Answer (score 1):

#### finish()

**[finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)** : **cuando es llamado este método la Activity es cerrada y destruida.** Este método puede ser llamado en donde sea necesario, por ejemplo activado al interactuar por algún elemento en la UI o al realizar alguna acción en nuestra aplicación.

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //llama finish() para cerrar Activity.
                finish();

            }
        });
```

#### onBackPressed()

**[onBackPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)**: Cuando implementas este método a diferencia de [finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) es llamado exclusivamente cuando das click al boton "back" y no necesitas llamar [finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) explicitamente dentro de el, esto si llamas `super.onBackPressed()` ya que internamente llama `finish()` .

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        //Si llamas super.onBackPressed(), esto internamente ejecuta finish().
        super.onBackPressed();            
}
```

si no llamas `super.onBackPressed()` y deseas terminé la Activity, tendrías que llamar `finish()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

     finish();            

}
```

Algo importante es que ambos métodos al estar en una Activity y teniendo un **[back stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)** vacio pueden cerrar la aplicación esto si [onBackPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) llama a finish() .

**Como resumen, [finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) finaliza la Actividad y la destruye, mientras que [onBackPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) puede detectar cuando activamos el boton "back", detecta el evento "retroceder" y ejecuta internamente `finish()`.**

Answer (score 1):

El método finish() terminará la actividad y el método onBackPressed() se ejecutará cuando el usuario presione la tecla virtual de retroceder. Para complementar y ya que no hay mucha información sobre estos métodos para fragmentos que es con lo que yo trabajo. Si queremos terminar la actividad en un fragmento será: "It is in a fragment"

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
   getActivity.finish()
}
```

Si trabajas con fragmentos y quieres que al presionar el botón de atrás aparezca un alert que diga si desea o no salir de la aplicación, el código lo debes de hacer en la actividad principal donde comenzó todo el llamado de fragmentos.
"it is in the main_activity":

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder mensaje=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    mensaje.setTitle("¿Desea Salir de la Aplicacion?");
    mensaje.setCancelable(false);
    mensaje.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    mensaje.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    mensaje.show();
}
```

Comment: Jose A. Huanca Ancajima, tengo también un método de onBackPressed en el activity principal y dentro tengo un fragment con algunos botones en navigation component tal como mencionas si estoy en un fragment y quiero ir atrás me manda la alerta, pero lo he intentado que solo me salga esa alerta cuando este en el activity principal es ahi donde done tengo ese detalle.