# Destruir una actividad

Tags: android, android-fragment, fragment

Buenas, tengo un problema con mi aplicacion, cuando abro una actividad y se termina de realizar lo que se requiere con esa actividad, se pasa a la otra, sin embargo, si el usuario presiona el boton back de su dispositivo este regresa a la actividad anterior, la cual deberia destruirse al momento de pasar a la siguiente, como puedo solucionar esto?

Un ejemplo mas claro:

Entro en mi actividad login (actividad) -> MainActivity (fragment) al darle al boton back me regresa al login, es decir, cuando pasa a la siguiente actividad esta no se destruye, como puedo eliminar esa ventana de la memoria para que no pueda ser accesada?

Comment: Dale una mirada a esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30368/diferencia-entre-finish-y-onbackpressed

Comment: Agrega tu código, @JesusMoran esto para que sea más útil para otros usuarios tu pregunta y vean lo que tratas de realizar. Puedes buscar en el sitio antes de preguntar, posiblemente ya existe una respuesta como en este caso, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3427/c%C3%B3mo-prevenir-ir-a-activity-anterior-en-android Saludos!

Comment: Mi codigo cada vez que llama a una nueva actividad, la termina con el finish(), el caso no es igual y la solucion no se aplica

Comment: Hola Jesus en tu parte del codigo que realizas el login de forma correcta incluye el finish(). Ej. if(usuario.equals(cuenta)){
           bandera = true;
           Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ItemListActivity.class);
           startActivity(detailIntent);
       }                                                                                                  if(bandera) { 
            finish();
        }else{
            msgtext("Error");
        } Cuando quieras regresar sale del programa pq la Activity login fue destruida

Comment: Si, ya lei con detenimiento las respuestas de las preguntas y las puse en practica, efectivamente no regresa a la actividad una vez colocado el finish,  pensaba que lo habia colocado en mi codigo, y revise y no es asi, mi error, muchas gracias

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SegundaActividad.class)
                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finishAffinity();